# Error writing to file when installing SQL Server 2012 64 bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

When trying to install SQL server 2012 x64 I get this error:

> Error writing to file: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient.Interfaces.DLL. Verify that you have access to that directory.

I've tried installing older versions and it always comes up with the same error.
In another post someone said install .NET 4.0 but when I try to install it it says I already have it installed so the installation won't continue.

Please help.

Comment: It looks like Analysis Services dll. Do you really need to install SSAS?

Answer (score 0):

try reinstall .net framework sometimes it's bugged. and second make sure you got fresh installed + complete. I already every time install and reinstall no problem tough.

what OS do you used btw?...

Comment: im using 8.1 64 bit, i haven't got around to upgrading to windows 10 yet. Will try reinstalling .net framework, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I couldn't find how to uninstall the .NET framework, so i downloaded the microsoft .net fix tool, now the error is this: Error writing to file: Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory.